# Does an IFilter Exist for Indexing Source Code Files?

Tags: indexing, search, ifilter

**Anybody know of an IFilter that can index source code files beyond what the "Plain Text" filter can provide, with possibly a custom "Property Set" specific to programming?**

For example, I have 835MB in 41,000 files and 8,200 folders in my "Code Library" folder. I would like to perform searches such as "select distinct attributes on properties" or "select class exceptions" or "select classes with nested private classes". Preferrably, the IFilter can distinguish between various languages, so I can perform a query like "select class exceptions in VB.NET" or "select 'resume next' in VBScript".

#### Other Examples

1. "select all enum from
   folder('microsoft source code') in
   namespace 'system.io'"

#### Update

- [2010.03.06] MSDN Code Search Preview at http://msdn.krugle.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at a static code analysis tool like NDepend that offers a feature called the Code Query Language http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL.

Comment: Interesting. Yet, I need something that works with Indexing Service and the other Windows search engines and non-compiled code. If I was to write an iFilter, the CQL is where I would start to defined the properties. Thanks.

Comment: Right - I should have also told you about ack (http://betterthangrep.com/) and exuberant ctags (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) for the time-being. 
I am working on something right now to duplicate the work that Andrew Begel proposed in his paper called Codifier on MS Research http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/abegel/papers/codifier.pdf. Would you like to contribute?

Comment: I just read this comment now. I wish we would get notifications. I added the link to "MSDN Code Search Preview" a couple days ago. Give me some time to check into it. I am interest in code searching. Someone has got to make this easier.